# Cannot show ARKit result in iPad Swift Playgrounds 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, arkit, swift-playground

I have been using Swift Playgrounds to test/teach ARKit. However, when I test the same codes written for previous version, running the code does not have error but also nothing is shown.

The code is something like this:

```
import UIKit
import ARKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class arViewController : UIViewController, ARSKViewDelegate {
    var sceneView: ARSKView!

    override func loadView() {
        sceneView = ARSKView(frame:CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 500.0, height: 600.0))
        sceneView.delegate = self
    ...
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = arViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. It appears as though the class for me isn’t even being accessed. I don’t know what the problem is.